# "On the cloud" or "in the cloud"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, programming

I would use this title for a blog about cloud computing. Which is correct — "*on* the cloud" or "*in* the cloud"?

Comment: As it is not a direct answer to the main question: What do you think of "amongst the clouds" for your blog title? Is it too long?

Comment: Yes it's too long. Thank you for the suggestion! =D

Answer (score 11):

**"In the cloud"** - You can use this phrase to say that a resource is part of the cloud. For example: "machine 1234 is in the cloud" or "the application was deployed in the cloud".

**"On the cloud"** - You can use this phrase to say that you're writing about a specific cloud. For example: "my post on the Amazon cloud"

**Google Results**

---

- 560K for "deployed in the cloud"
- 249K for "deployed to the cloud"
- 236K for "deployed on the cloud"
- 10K for "deployed into the cloud"

---

- 1.1M for "machine in the cloud"
- 347K for "machine on the cloud"

---

- 2.5M for "application in the cloud"
- 1.3M for "application on the cloud"

---

- 3.3M for "running on the cloud"
- 3.2M for "running in the cloud"

Comment: I wouldn't talk about a specific cloud. I would be more generic. Do you have an alternative to "in the cloud" which gives the same meaning?

Comment: A nice name (but already taken by a scientific paper) is [Above the Clouds](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2009/EECS-2009-28.html).

Comment: I thougt to use Cloud (not cloudS) because I would to talk about the Internet which is the big Cloud we know. But if I use the plural, I could use "in the clouds" as title too.

Comment: "In the clouds" sounds good. I like this name.

Comment: I'm thinking about "into the cloud"

Comment: Erm… “writing about *an* specific cloud” → something’s wrong there.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the phrase originated in the habit of drawing the internet as a cloud shape on network diagrams. Diagramming products such as Visio provide cloud shapes in their network diagram templates.

Since servers are then drawn inside the cloud shape, the phrase *in the cloud* is a better reflection of the diagrammatic usage.

Anyway, clouds are insubstantial things unable to bear the weight of a cluster of big-iron servers attempting to perch perilously **on** top. Much better to nestle your servers **in** the warm fuzzy nurturing embrace of the cloud whose opaqueness hides them from nasty predators.

[image: Network diagram]

[image: Cloud computing]
*Images from Wikipedia*

Comment: That's right. Using "in" is more suitable. But unfortunately the domain is occupied while the one with "on" is free. Do you have an alternative that gives the same meaning of "in the cloud"?

Comment: What fratricidal cuckoo occupies the "in the cloud" domain? Why cannot "in the cloud" accommodate multiple meanings (as so many English words and expressions are happy to do)? Perhaps anyone moving critical services into the cloud has their head in the clouds?

Comment: Depending on your attitude to your servers you could sweep them "under the cloud"!

Comment: "into the cloud" could be a nice! and it's free too!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it would be “in the cloud”.

Answer (score 2):

"In the cloud" is where your data is stored, or where your processing takes place, in the cloud computing paradigm.

"On the cloud" might however be a nice blog title. It means you are writing "on the cloud", where "on" means "regarding".

You are writing on "the cloud" as a concept, so there is no need to pluralise, even though you will doubtless write about a number of different "clouds".

See Stephen King's "On Writing", Carl Rogers' "On Becoming A Person", John Scanlan's "On Garbage".

Answer (score 1):

"On" the cloud - could be taken to mean that you are on the cloud of cloud computing taken in context of "I am on cloud nine"

"In" the cloud - seems to convey that you are right in the midst of all the latest happenings in the cloud computing space.

I don't think that there is a specific right or wrong here. It depends on the general direction / viewpoint that your blog is trying to convey.

Considering the morass that usually surrounds a term like "Cloud Computing", "Demystifying the Cloud" might also not be a bad option!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thougt to use "in" but unfortunately the domain is occupied. I agree with you. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: How about "Head in the clouds" :-) :-)

Comment: that's too long for a domain :(

Comment: it's only one character longer than washingtonpost.com

Answer (score 0):

@Bruno - I thought we say 'the application was deployed to the cloud' instead of 'in the cloud'

**Edit: Added answer** - I think it best to use 'on' or 'in' or 'to' depending on the context. If you are going to say

'... is running on the machine' , ' ... is running on the cloud' ,

'... is deployed to the machine' , ' ... is deployed to the cloud' ,

Comment: yes, some people say "on the cloud". With "cloud computing", a google search for "in the cloud" bring two times more results though.

Comment: Google results: 560K for **deployed in the cloud**, 249K for "deployed to the cloud", 236K for "deployed on the cloud" and 10K for "deployed into the cloud"

Comment: To be precise, the application is running *on* a computer, which is *in* the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that in the body of the question you have not started the phrases with a capital letter, is it to be presumed that the phrase is only a part of the blog title?

In that case, a lot can depend on the full blog title.

However, a short 'On the Cloud' would be nice, both grammatically as well as technically. (note the capitalization again, *the Cloud*: as in cloud computing environment)