# What preposition should I use when talking about computer and softwares

Tags: prepositions, american-english

My question is about prepositions and what to use when talking about computer and software.

1. I will Install a software (**in,on,into**) my computer
2. a software was installed (**in,on,into**) my computer

Comment: Related: *[Which is right: “In one of the computers” or “On one of the computers”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152880)*; *[To download something ON or ONTO a device?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123571)*, *[Preposition IN Vs Preposition ON when writing by an electronic device](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137687)*; *[“On the cloud” or “in the cloud”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7191)*,

Comment: There is no such thing as "a software" or "softwares" except in some Indian dialects. *Software* is uncountable in standard American or British English.

Answer (score 0):

You would use "on".

> I installed software **on** my computer.
>
> (A piece of) software was installed **on** my computer.

Answer (score 0):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=install%20in%20a%20computer%2Cinstall%20on%20a%20computer%2Cinstall%20into%20a%20computer&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinstall%20in%20a%20computer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinstall%20on%20a%20computer%3B%2Cc0) shows that actually both  ***in*** and ***on*** are equally used referring to softwares or other devices that are installed in/on a computer.

- You can also purchase a  [software](https://books.google.it/books?id=yYo9z93TDOQC&pg=PA31&dq=%22install%20in%20a%20computer%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=M15MVYHpD4yU7Qa4_YHIAQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22install%20in%20a%20computer%22&f=false) R... you ***install in*** a computer that you purchase and configure it to connect to your printing engine.
- How would you determine what type of CD-ROM to ***[install](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZRn1ABMv0acC&q=%22install%20in%20a%20computer%22&dq=%22install%20in%20a%20computer%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=r15MVZCtH-uy7QbDnICwBg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ) in*** a computer?
- This software is usually very easy to ***[install](https://books.google.it/books?id=sgejcEc8nwEC&q=%22install%20on%20a%20computer%22&dq=%22install%20on%20a%20computer%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=A19MVYqGGIeM7AbXzIGwAg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ) on*** a computer. You can also upgrade to the latest..
- Packet sniffers are processes that a superuser can ***[install](https://books.google.it/books?id=hlIqAQAAMAAJ&q=%22install%20on%20a%20computer%22&dq=%22install%20on%20a%20computer%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=T19MVfjKJ8iy7Qar2YCACg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ) on*** a computer

Answer (score -1):

Didn't see the bottom half.

1. I will install software on my computer
2. Software was installed on my computer

Some grammatical corrections as well :)

Hope that answers the question!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and as such answers are expected to stand alone— without justification, including suitable references, links, or examples, you are merely presenting opinion. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.